# Angular 4 : Click on a link with parameters

Tags: javascript, angular

I am quite new to Angular 4. I have an anchor tag which upon clicking it should redirect me to a link where I need to pass parameters as well. I am not sure if my approach is right or wrong. But more importantly, how do I pass parameters? I need guidance.

**form.component.html:**

```
<a (click)="myFunc()" href="" target="_blank">Go to mymodule</a><br />
```

**form.component.ts**

```
myFunc() {
  console.log("function called");
  window.open('../myURL/mypage.jsp?rurl=' + encodeURIComponent($('display').attr('href')));
  }
```

Comment: Whats $('display').attr('href') ? and why your using jquery here?

Comment: I need to call a servlet. I was trying out with jquery. though it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should use [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router) to navigate like this:

```
myFunc() {
  console.log("function called");
  this.router.navigate(['../myURL'], {queryParams:{rurl: "someId"}})
 }
```

**Also**, don't forget to import `Router`  like this:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

this.router = Router;
```

**NOTE:** using `../` before an URL makes router go up by one level.

Answer (score 0):

If You you want to redirect outside of application:

```
myFunc(){
   window.location.href = `full_url?rurl=${encodeURIComponent(display)})`;
}
```

If You you want to navigate to page  inside of  your application:

```
myFunc(){
this.router.navigate(['/navigation_route'], {queryParams:{returnRoute: 'any_path'});
}
```

Comment: what about href link ?

Comment: that is case 1 (outside application for  example - payment gateway)

Answer (score 0):

**Using [routerLink] :**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route-name', id]" href="">Go to mymodule</a>
```

also you shouldn't forget to change routing config like :

```
[path: 'route-name/:id', component:ComponentName, pathMatch: 'full']
```

**Using navigateByUrl :**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) { }

myFunc = function () {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/route-name', {queryParams:{param-key: param-value}});
};
```