# How to submit a form with an a tag in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, submit

I have form data in hidden input fields that I want to use to submit when a user clicks on an `<a>` tag.

```
<form action="/submit/form/link">
  <input type="hidden" [attr.value]="orderNumber.id" />
  <input type="hidden" [attr.value]="orderNumber.country" />
  <a>start order process</a>
</form>
```

I cannot seem to find any examples of submitting a form with an `<a>` tag. I see I can submit with `<input type="submit" />` or `<button type="submit">submit</button>`, but I need to use an `<a>` tag here.

I see that I can use the `(click)` attribute in my `<a>` tag to then run a function in my `.ts` file, so something like

```
<a (click)="startOrderProcess()">start order process</a>
```

But then I cannot find examples on how to submit a form to go to the action link `/submit/form/link` programmatically in my `.ts` file.

How do I submit a form above with the hidden input data using an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Is /submit/form/link the same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

1. In module.ts file, `import { FormsModule } from @angular/forms`
2. Implement a template-driven form.
3. In component.ts file, `import { Router } from @angular/router` & `import { ngForm } from '@angular/forms`
4. In component.ts file, add `constructor(private router: Router) {}`
5. In component.html file, add `<form #formName = 'ngForm'>` & `<a (click)="startOrderProcess(formName)">`
6. In your component.ts file, inside the function called on click of anchor tag, do the following, 
   `startOrderProcess(form:NgForm) {
   console.log(form.value);
   this.router.navigate(['/submit/form/link']); }`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import the angular router :

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router"
```

Then inject it in your component constructor :

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

And finally call the .navigate method in your startOrderProcess() function :

```
this.router.navigate(['/submit/form/link']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need the hidden input fields here.

Assuming orderNumber.id and orderNumber.country are the values you want to submit,you can simply use a function on click for this.

```
<a (click)="startOrderProcess()">start order process</a>
```

Inside startOrderProcess(),

```
// if same component
startOrderProcess() {
  // do whatever you want 
}



// if another component
startOrderProcess() {
   this.router.navigate(['/submit/form/link']);
}
```

You will need to pass the parameters also in the latter.

Check this [Angular 4 : Click on a link with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243916/angular-4-click-on-a-link-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

bind input fields with ngModel directive.
call a function on click on link
read ngModel data in class and use it to process